# symfony2 not equal values in fields

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I have class with many variables. Few of them are File types

```
 class Proposal {
/**
 *  @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="File")
 *  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="clientCommFile_id", referencedColumnName="id")  */
private $clientCommFile;

/**
 *  @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="File")
 *  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="contractFile_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $contractFile;

/**
 *  @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="File")
 *  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="proposalFile_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $proposalFile;
```

I need do create some validation rule to validate which will inspect ids of files. The ids must be different because it referres to files in database.
Is some way, how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want clientCommFile, contractFile and proposalFile to be different? Assuming one can just compare objects, here is how it goes:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext;

/**
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"areFilesValid"})
 */
class Proposal {

    // ..

    public function areFilesValid(ExecutionContext $context) {
        if($this->clientCommFile != null && $this->clientCommFile->equals($this->contractFile)){
            $propertyPath = $context->getPropertyPath() . '.options';
            $context->setPropertyPath($propertyPath);
            $context->addViolation('ClientCommFile and ContractFile are equal', array(), null);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you must implement the equals method on your objects.

If it gets more complicated or you need Database access, have a look at [custom validators](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html)

Comment: Database access is not needed here. Can I just comapare somehow file ids I get from form. My intention is: add ids into array, order asc and comare wheter the i-1 index equals i index. Instead callback method, I used getter method, but it doesnt work